# ¿De que forma debo de interactuar con un arreglo entero privado en una clase?

Tags: c++

pues tengo una duda referente en cuanto a como deberia de interactuar con el arreglo entero privado de mi clase, ya que tengo unas funciones donde estoy haciendo uso de ella. Para ser mas exacto tengo problemas en la funcion setArray,getArray y get_assign_Array.

De igual manera planeba hacer uso de la variable N para que el usuario le diera el valor al tamaño del arreglo, pero por lo visto no se puede realizar, ¿Existe alguna manera de asignarle el valor del tamaño del arreglo a un arreglo adentro de una clase?

Les dejo el codigo.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <istream>

using namespace std;

class Ej
{
private:
    int N;
    int P_array[N];
    
public:
    Ej();
    void setN(int n);
    int getN();
    void SetArray(int n[]);
    void get_Assign_Array(int n[]);//LE ASIGNA LOS VALORES DE P_ARRAY A UN ARREGLO o. 0
    void getArray();//IMPRIME EL ARREGLO, EN TEORIA NO SE PUEDE REGRESAR UN ARREGLO DE ENTERO ´•͜ •`
    void Proc_princ();
    void ingreso_arreglo_n();//FUNCION QUE ASIGNA LOS VALORES INGRESADOS A N Y AL ARREGLO (ᴗ.ᴗ)
    int menu();

};

Ej::Ej(){}
void Ej::setN(int n)
{
    N=n;
}
int Ej::getN()
{
    return N;
}
void Ej::SetArray(int n[])
{
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        P_array[i]=n[i];
    }
}
void Ej::get_Assign_Array(int n[])
{
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        n[i]=P_array[i];
    }
}
void Ej::getArray()
{
    cout<<endl<<"ARREGLO: (";
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        cout<<P_array[i]<<",";
    }
    cout<<")";
}
void Ej::ingreso_arreglo_n()
{
    char s[55];
    bool b1=false, b2=false, b3=false;
    int aux, i=0;
    int bigaux[N];
    cout<<"********************************************"<<endl;
    cout<<"EJECUTANDO..."<<endl<<endl;
    Sleep(500);
    cout<<"\t BIENVENIDO"<<endl;
    
    
    //<LECTURA DE TAMAÑO DE ARREGLO...>
    do
    {
    cout<<"EMPECEMOS POR DECIRME EL TAMAÑO DEL ARREGLO A UTILIZAR..."<<endl<<">"; cin.getline(s,55);
    if(s[0]>=64 && s[0]<=90) b2=true;
    if(s[0]>=97 && s[0]<=122) b3=true;
    if(b2 || b3)
      {
      cout<<endl<<"VALOR INTRODUCIDO DE ORIGEN NO NUMERICO, INTRODUZCA UN ENTERO VALIDO...."<<endl;
      b1=true;
      }
    aux=atoi(s);
    if(aux!=0) b1=false;
    b2=false;
    b3=false;
    }while(b1);
    setN(atoi(s));
    // </LECTURA DE TAMAÑO DE ARREGLO...>
    
    // <LECTURA DE ENTEROS PARA SU POSTERIOR ASIGNACION AL ARREGLO...>
    do
    {
    cout<<endl<<"AHORA QUE DECIDIO EL TAMAÑO, POR FAVOR RELLENE EL ARREGLO..."<<endl;
    cout<<"INTRODUZCA EL VALOR DEL ENTERO EN EL INDICE #"<<i<<"...." <<endl<<">"; cin.getline(s,55);
    if(s[0]>=64 && s[0]<=90) b2=true;
    if(s[0]>=97 && s[0]<=122) b3=true;
    if(b2 || b3)
      {
      cout<<endl<<"VALOR INTRODUCIDO DE ORIGEN NO NUMERICO, INTRODUZCA UN ENTERO VALIDO...."<<endl;
      b1=true;
      i=0;
      }
    aux=atoi(s);
    if(aux!=0)
    {
        bigaux[i]=atoi(s);
        i++;
    }
    if(i==N)b1=false;
    b2=false;
    b3=false;
    }while(b1);
    // </LECTURA DE ENTEROS PARA SU POSTERIOR ASIGNACION AL ARREGLO...>
    SetArray(bigaux);
    
    
    
    
}

int Ej::menu()
{
    char aux[55]="";
    int a;
    cout<< "[ 1 ] - - - - - - - - - Ejecutar metodo ExisteElemento."<<endl;
    cout<< "[ 2 ] - - - - - - - - - Ejecutar metodo Ocurrencia."<<endl;
    cout<< "[ 3 ] - - - - - - - - - Ejecutar metodo Suma."<<endl;
    cout<< "[ 4 ] - - - - - - - - - Ejecutar metodo Ordenar."<<endl;
    cout<< "[ 5 ] - - - - - - - - - Salir del Programa."<<endl;
    cout<<"Ingrese una opcion......."<<endl; cout<<">";
    cin.getline(aux,55); a=atoi(aux); return a;
}
void Ej::Proc_princ()
{
  
    int opc=0;
    ingreso_arreglo_n();
    
    //CERRADO X RENOVACION...
    /*
    do
    {
        opc=menu();
        switch(opc)
        {
            case 1:
                
                break;
            case 2:
                
                break;
            case 3:
                
                break;
            case 4: 
                
                break;
            case 5: 
                break;
            default:
                cout<<endl<<"OPCION INCORRECTA (ᴗ.ᴗ), INTRODUZCA UN PARAMETRO VALIDO ENTRE EL RANGO DE OPCIONES..."<<endl;
        }
    } while(opc!=5);  */
}
int main()
{
Ej p;
p.Proc_princ();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Si lo sabes en tiempo de compilacion, usa templates. Pero como dices que el usuario le da el valor al tamaño, lo mejor seria que utilizaras `std::vector`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ¿Existe alguna manera de asignarle el valor del tamaño del arreglo a un arreglo adentro de una clase?

Si, las plantillas.

---

Para entender la respuesta anterior, debes entender cómo funcionan los arreglos.

En C++ un arreglo en memoria automática<sup>1</sup> debe tener un tamaño conocido en tiempo de compilación. Esto es necesario porque el compilador necesita conocer el tamaño de los objetos para instanciarlos. Así que, tu código no compilaría:

```
class Ej
{
private:
    int N;          // ¿Qué valor tiene 'N'?
    int P_array[N]; // ¿Cuántos enteros estoy reservando aquí?
...
};

...

std::cout << sizeof(Ej); // ¿Qué tamaño tiene 'Ej'?
```

Puedes otorgarle a `Ej` un tamaño conocido en tiempo de compilación usando plantillas:

```
template <std::size_t N>
class Ej
{
private:
    int P_array[N]; // Reservamos 'N' enteros.
...
};

...

std::cout << sizeof(Ej<3>); // 'Ej<3>' tendrá un tamaño de 12 bytes.
```

Pero esto implica que no puedes cambiar el tamaño en tiempo de compilación, si realmente necesitas cambiar el tamaño dinámicamente usa un contenedor:

```
class Ej
{
private:
    std::vector<int> P_array; // std::vector ya tiene un contandor interno de tamaño
...
};
```

---

<sup>1</sup>La memoria automática es aquella que no se pide a mano con `new`.